# SAS Community: How do I remove duplicates of one variable but only if it meets the condition of another variable?

Tags: duplicates, sas

I have a large dataset in SAS with two main variables that are relevant for this quesiton:

```
 1. ID: every row has its own unique ID, however some rows are repeated therefore many IDs are repeated as well 

 2. Gratuation: this is a categorical "Yes or No" variable
```

I am trying create a new dataset that includes all of the people who have a "Yes" under their graduation variable, despite whether their ID is duplicated or not. And for those who have a "No" under the graduation variable, I want it to remove any rows that have a duplicate ID, keeping only the first occurance of the duplicated ID.

I have tried the following codes however none are working the way I want them to.

```
DATA Library.Narrowed_Down;
Set Library.Students;
If graduation = "Yes" then output;
ELSE IF first.ID then output; 
RUN;
```

However this only included all of the people who have graduated and completely excluded everyone who has not, instead of just removing the duplicates.

I have also tried:

```
DATA Library.Narrowed_Down;
Set Library.Students;
If graduation = "Yes" then output;
ELSE IF graduation = "No" and not_id_seen then do; 
output;
id_seen=1; 
RUN;
```

And:

```
DATA Library.Narrowed_Down(drop=cnt);
Set Library.Students;
If graduation = "Yes" then output;
ELSE IF graduation = "No" then do; 
if not cnt then do;
output;
cnt = 1; 
end;
end;
RUN;
```

And:

```
DATA Library.Narrowed_Down;
Set Library.Students;
by ID;
if first.ID or exposure = "Yes"; 
RUN;
```

Comment: I'm confused about the ID variable? Is ID unique or can there be multiple rows with the same ID value?

Comment: Also, if multiple rows with the same ID can occur, can they have Gratuation = 'Y' in one row and Gratuation = 'N' in another?

Comment: Why do you need the FIRST observation? Are there other variables in the dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Can you update your question to include some example data? Assuming each ID has a consistent value for Graduation (i.e. all "Yes" or all "No") then I think your first code works fine (with a BY statement added):

```
data have ;
  input ID Graduation $3. ;
  cards ;
1 Yes
1 Yes
2 Yes
3 No
3 No
4 No
;

data want;
  set have ;
  by id ;
  if graduation = "Yes" then output;
  else if first.ID then output; 
run ;

proc print data=want ;
run ;
```

Returns:

```
Obs    ID    Graduation

 1      1       Yes
 2      1       Yes
 3      2       Yes
 4      3       No
 5      4       No
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the status of GRADUATION you could just take the MAX() of that variable.  Then a single 'Yes' will win out over any number of 'No'.

```
proc sql;
  create table want as
    select id,max(graduation) as graduation 
    from have
    group by id
  ;
quit;
```

If you really need find the first Yes record, but are willing to accept the last No record when there is no Yes record then do something like this:

```
data want;
  set have;
  by id;
  if first.id then any_yes=0;
  if graduation='Yes' and not any_yes then do;
    output;
    any_yes=1;
  end;
  if last.id and not any_yes then output;
run;
```

If you really must have the first No record when there are no Yes records you will need to pass through the data twice.

```
data want;
do until (last.id);
  set have;
  by id;
  if graduation=='Yes' then any_yes=1;
end;
do until (last.id);
  set have;
  by id;
  if first.id and not any_yes then output;
  else if graduation='Yes' and any_yes then do;
    output;
    any_yes=0;
  end;
end;
run;
```